# How to use inline documentation for tests in rust

Tags: testing, rust

I am trying to get rust to test an example from my inline documentation. I wrote the following code:

````
#[derive(Clone)]
#[derive(PartialEq)]
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Color {
    Black = 1,
    Empty = 0,
    White = -1
}
/// Chages Color to the next player
///
/// Returns: White if player is Black, Black if player is White and Empty if
/// player is Empty.
///
/// Examlple
/// ```
/// assert_eq!(flip(&Color::White),Color::Black);
///```

// Invariant Color must represent Black as 1, Empty as 0 and White as -1!
fn flip(player: &Color)->Color{
    let intrepresentation :i8 = (player.clone() as i8) * (-1);
    unsafe{
        std::mem::transmute(intrepresentation)
    }
}
fn  main() {
    assert_eq!(flip(&Color::White),Color::Black);
}
````

Then I run

```
rustdoc --test src/main.rs
```

Which gave me:

```
running 1 test
test src/main.rs - flip (line 16) ... FAILED

failures:

---- src/main.rs - flip (line 16) stdout ----
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type or module `Color`
 --> src/main.rs:17:18
  |
3 | assert_eq!(flip(&Color::White),Color::Black);
  |                  ^^^^^ use of undeclared type or module `Color`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type or module `Color`
 --> src/main.rs:17:32
  |
3 | assert_eq!(flip(&Color::White),Color::Black);
  |                                ^^^^^ use of undeclared type or module `Color`

error[E0425]: cannot find function `flip` in this scope
 --> src/main.rs:17:12
  |
3 | assert_eq!(flip(&Color::White),Color::Black);
  |            ^^^^ not found in this scope

error: aborting due to 3 previous errors

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0425, E0433.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0425`.
Couldn't compile the test.

failures:
    src/main.rs - flip (line 16)

test result: FAILED. 0 passed; 1 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out
```

How can I get rustc to find flip and Color. The test runs fine in the main function. I have also tried the command:

```
cargo test
```

but that did not run any tests.

I have tried add the following line to the example:

```
   /// use crate::{flip, Color};
```

making:

````
// Chages Color to the next player
///
/// Returns: White if player is Black, Black if player is White and Empty if
/// player is Empty.
///
/// Examlple
/// ```
/// use crate::{flip, Color};
/// assert_eq!(flip(&Color::White),Color::Black);
///```
````

but that gives an error

```
martin@martin-laptop:~/test_code$ rustdoc --test src/main.rs 

running 1 test
test src/main.rs - main (line 23) ... FAILED

failures:

---- src/main.rs - main (line 23) stdout ----
error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate::Color`
 --> src/main.rs:24:14
  |
3 | use crate::{ Color};
  |              ^^^^^ no `Color` in the root

error[E0425]: cannot find function `flip` in this scope
 --> src/main.rs:25:12
  |
4 | assert_eq!(flip(&Color::White),Color::Black);
  |            ^^^^ not found in this scope

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0425, E0432.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0425`.
Couldn't compile the test.

failures:
    src/main.rs - main (line 23)

test result: FAILED. 0 passed; 1 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out
```

I have also tried to Color and flip  as public:

````
#[derive(Clone)]
#[derive(PartialEq)]
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Color {
    Black = 1,
    Empty = 0,
    White = -1
}

/// Chages Color to the next player
///
/// Returns: White if player is Black, Black if player is White and Empty if
/// player is Empty.
///
/// Examlple
/// ```
/// use crate::{flip, Color};
/// use std::env;
/// assert_eq!(flip(&Color::White),Color::Black);
///```

// Invariant Color must represent Black as 1, Empty as 0 and White as -1!

pub fn flip(player: &Color)->Color{
    let intrepresentation :i8 = (player.clone() as i8) * (-1);
    unsafe{
        std::mem::transmute(intrepresentation)
    }
}
fn  main() {
    assert_eq!(flip(&Color::White),Color::Black);
}
````

but that gave the same error.

Comment: why don't you add use lines ? `use crate::{flip, Color};`

Comment: What are use lines?

Comment: somehow like import in python

Comment: need to add pub to Color and flip I guess sorry I'm not very used to write doc in rust and there is not much doc https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/how-to-write-documentation.html

Comment: Note that doc tests only work for library crates (which can be linked with the test executable), not for program crates.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Doc tests (tests inside ```` /// ``` ````) are **compiled separately** as tiny programs of their own. Therefore:

- They can only access public items: `pub mod`, `pub fn`, `pub struct`, ...
- They can only access *library crates* that export items to be used by other crates — if your program is in `main.rs` then it's a *binary crate*.
- You have to fully qualify or `use` the names, like `use my_library::Color;`.

If you want to test things that don't fit this, then you should use `#[test]` tests instead:

```rust
#[test]
fn flip_test() {
    assert_eq!(flip(&Color::White), Color::Black);
}
```

Any function located anywhere in your program with the attribute `#[test]` will be run as a test. So, they can access private items since they're in the same module  (or a submodule; it's common to put them inside a module named `tests` in the same file, with `mod tests { ... }`).

You can find more information about how to write test functions and organize your tests at [The Rust Programming Language: How to Write Tests](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-01-writing-tests.html).

---

> I have also tried to Color and flip as public:
>
> ```
> /// use crate::{flip, Color};
> ```

This doesn't work because `crate` refers to the current crate, which for a doc test is **the test program**, not your main crate.